# SQL Server DeleteFolder Job ran successfully but it doesn't deleted the folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xp-cmdshell

I have a job to delete past 15 days folder in SQL Server. The job run successfully and delete the folder in local SQL Server.

But it runs successfully and does not delete the folder in another SQL Server which is accessed by remote desktop connection.

Please suggest how to solve it. Is it permission problem?

The following is the code I use

```
{
--Script to enable the XP_CMDSHELL
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO

DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000)

DECLARE @folderName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup

SET @folderName = + GETDATE()-15 --(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE()-15, 'yyyy_mm_dd'))  -- 15 days back date folder name
SET @folderName =  CONVERT(varchar(4),YEAR(@folderName)) + '_' + Right('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2),MONTH(@folderName)),2) + '_' + Right('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DAY(@folderName)),2) 
SET @path = 'D:\FTP-Snapshots\' + @folderName -- Folder path 
SET @cmd = 'RD ' + @path + ' /S /Q' -- Delete Files and the Folder IF all files deletions were successful.

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
}
```

Comment: Is the folder on other SQL server shared with appropriate rights and permission? Also why not schedule a similar SQL agent job on another server as well to check the same?

Comment: I have already assigned same SQL agent job in that server. it run successfully but not deleting the folder.

Comment: Ok, are you deleting the similar file on both the servers? Means are u deleting the files with same extension like .bak or files are of different types?

Comment: If you print the @cmd variable value is this correct? Which user is executing the job?

Comment: @KASQLDBA yes I am deleting the similar files. It work in my Local computer.

Comment: @Giova I believe cmd value is correct since it is working in my local computer. User right is sysadmin

Comment: I the used date format correct in remote system? Is the same?

Comment: yeah.. i did also doubt that,... So hard code the path name 'D:\FTP-Snapshots\2015_07_15'. it is not deleted. So I assume this is not folder name problem

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of my hard times, I found that I have problem in "Permission". Since I am using "xp_cmdshell" which use window log in permission to delete the folder.
I ask my server guy to give me "Modify permission" which can delete the folder. It solve my whole problem. Thanks guys